# How to check file completely arrived/copied?

Tags: c, linux, file, file-read

We have a service which process files from a particular folder, whenever files arrived/copied to that folder. Now, before file arrives completely Service is processing and failing with errors. Now, how to check and read only when file completely copied?

The service is running on Linux. After, failing with "ERR_READING", the process will sleep for 5 secs. Even, the process fails to read the file. May be reading the file before completely copied may corrupting the file

Below is the code we are using to read data from file:

```
int file_read( char *fname, TRANSACTION **tr )
{
    int ret;
    FILE    *fp;

    fp = fopen( fname, "r" );
    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        return( NO_FILE );
    }

    if(( ret = tr_read_tran( fp, tr ))!=0)
        {
        sleep(5);
        ret = tr_read_tran( fp, tr );
    }

    fclose( fp );

    return( ret );
}


static int tr_read_tran( FILE *fp, TRANSACTION **tr )
{
    int ret,
        t;
    char    *p,
        *bkpt,
        buf[ BUFSIZE ];

    if( fgets( buf, BUFSIZE, fp ) == NULL )
    {
        return( ERR_READING );   ***//Failing here because of file not completeley arrived***
    }
   ....
   ...
   ret = //gets value for ret

    return( ret )
}
```

Comment: Please expand on what errors you have - plus the file, is it actuary 2 lines of text.

Comment: Tap into filesystem notifications, which are OS-dependent but still available on pretty much any system. Using that, only start processing the file after it was closed. For Linux, use e.g. "iwatch -e close_write ..." to watch for writes to a file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what platform is this running on (Windows, a standard Unix flavor) ? An answer involving locking may-well vary greatly depending on that info.

Comment: @WhozCraig, service runs on Linux

Comment: offtopic: why do you need to have `ret = tr_read_tran( fp, tr );` for second time inside `if`?

Comment: "*May be reading the file before completely copied may corrupting the file*" opening the file for reading only (mode `"r"`) does not harm the file, no matter how much of it "had arrived" yet.

Comment: If using `inotify` wait for the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Answer (score 1):

You could just create separate folder for files that are downloaded. 
Then just rename/move them to working directory.

Another way could be to append name with some "special" characters, that will tell service that file is still downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should set **ret** to something in tr_read_tran() function...

```
#define NOT_ERROR 100000   // any value not zero

static int tr_read_tran( FILE *fp, TRANSACTION **tr )
{
    int ret = NOT_ERROR,
        t;
    char    *p,
        *bkpt,
        buf[ BUFSIZE ];

    if( fgets( buf, BUFSIZE, fp ) == NULL )
    {
        return( ERR_READING );   ***//Failing here because of file not completeley arrived***
    }

    return( ret )
}
```

Currently it is not initialized to any value.

Comment: Correct, but somehow does not answer the question, so this would have better suited as comment.

Comment: The question has been edited since I posted the answer. The addition of setting the ret value. At the time, it was good!   :-)

Comment: Please excuse, I did not wanted to express that it's content wasn't good. It simply does not anwser the question "*How to check file completely arrived/copied?*".

Answer (score 0):

**So many options..**

here is a few:

- use the filesystem events:

on linux:
 http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

on windows:
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342da5th(v=vs.90).aspx

- use a checksum on clients, and on server, to ensure file integrity, before processing.
- create an error handler in your c program, that will ensure a retry on errors. think try/catch, except this doesnt actually exist in c, so instead use setjmp, and longjmp http://www.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/longjump_try_trow_catch.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this problem is

1) Changes in Producer code:  "Make your producer (the creator of the file") to write the file contents to /tmp folder; and move the file from /tmp folder to the source folder;

```
                             [or]
```

2)

a) Change in Producer code: "Make your producer to write in source foleder with _part extension like "Myfile.txt._part" on completion of write operation then remove the last extension added to it; so the file name will be "Myfile.txt";

b) Changes in consumer code: "Make your consumer not to open any files that has last extension with ._part;